# boolean onClickEventListener purpose of the return

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

Good day all

What is the purpose of the return assignment in a

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
    //some code here    
    return false;
}
```

I am only able to trace this method as far baack as:

ExpandableListView.class:

```
public interface OnGroupClickListener {
        boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView var1, View var2, int var3, long var4);
    }
```

I have been using this for a while, but could never quite understand its purpose

Comment: what is wrong with the documentation? `Returns
boolean True if the click was handled`

Comment: @Selvin thanks for this, please comment link, I would like to read up on this.

Comment: Sorry i'm to lazy for google search of OnGroupClickListener's official documentation... I'm pretty sure that you understand me as you didn't it either

Comment: @Selvin so glad I found a  "trolling lazy noobs" like me :p thanks (p.s. I did but didn't find what I was looking for)

Answer (score 1):

Purpose behind the systematic approach to handle click listener for group of listview that we can say header of each group.Suppose there is any requirement where you want to just expand each group as a display purpose and you don't want any click on group header then you can return false there.So expand collapse process will be not there.You will programmatically expand all group at start up / setting up list.

Answer (score 1):

Events like onClickListener have a boolean return value to indicate that the event were triggered or not.

This way, a long click event will not trigger a click event too.